# Injective version of Horseshoe lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

> Do we have an injective version of [Horseshoe lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_lemma)?

I am trying to construct injective resolution of a chain complex. If there exits an injective version of Horseshoe lemma, then I guess I know how to construct the injective resolution.

Comment: You can easily prove the injective analogue of the horse shoe lemma by applying the projective version to the dual category (note that the dual of ab abelian category is again abelian, so we can do that).

Comment: It's written in the link you provide: "If $\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian category with enough injectives, the dual statement also holds."

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Get it